# My problem is System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

When I am inputting wrong username and password this error shows

this is my code

```
RegLog reuser = res.ResultAs<RegLog>(); //database result <-- Error Occurs here.
```

any solution? I already tried to declare it as `var` but error still persist.
Thank you.

Comment: It sounds  like `res` is null.

Comment: Please provide additional information on how `res` is created. The only way this code would generate a null reference exception would be for `res` to be null, or for some code in `ResultAs` to actually be generating the exception. Not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

It is because for some reason (probably **wrong username and password**), the variable `res` is null.

Try to check a null reference before using `res`.

Example: `if(res == null) { //do something }`